# Amazon S3 upload image - using angular js directly from browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload images from my browser to Amazon S3 directly, using angular js.

Below is my code.

```
function _upload($files) {
                $scope.file = $files[0];
                $scope.creds = {
                    access_key: '***',
                    secret_key: '***',
                    bucket: 'sabari-test'
                };

                var bucket = new AWS.S3({
                    params: {
                        Bucket: $scope.creds.bucket
                    }
                });
                AWS.config.accessKeyId = $scope.creds.access_key;
                AWS.config.secretAccessKey = $scope.creds.secret_key;
                AWS.config.region = 'us-west-2';

                // AWS.

                if ($scope.file) {
                    // Perform File Size Check First
                    var fileSize = Math.round(parseInt($scope.file.size));
                    if (fileSize > $scope.sizeLimit) {
                        console.log('Sorry, your attachment is too big.');
                        return false;
                    }
                    // Prepend Unique String To Prevent Overwrites
                    var uniqueFileName = 'hai' + '-' + $scope.file.name;

                    var params = {
                        Key: uniqueFileName,
                        ContentType: $scope.file.type,
                        Body: $scope.file,
                        ServerSideEncryption: 'AES256'
                    };

                    bucket.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err.message);
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            // Upload Successfully Finished
                            console.log('File Uploaded Successfully');
                        }
                    })
                } else {
                    // No File Selected
                    console.log('Please select a file to upload');
                }
            }
```

I get the below error:

"Missing credentials in config"

Please let me know what is the missing credential?

Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity: you have this in your JS file where anyone can see it? Are you aware that anyone would have access to your Amazon S3 credentials? Don't you want to do this in the back-end instead?

Comment: Yes I am .Thanks.  I am doing this to achieve the flow working. I will route through node js, later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace these lines:

```
            var bucket = new AWS.S3({
                params: {
                    Bucket: $scope.creds.bucket
                }
            });
            AWS.config.accessKeyId = $scope.creds.access_key;
            AWS.config.secretAccessKey = $scope.creds.secret_key;
            AWS.config.region = 'us-west-2';
```

With this:

```
            var bucket = new AWS.S3({
                region = 'us-west-2',
                credentials: new AWS.Credentials($scope.creds.access_key, $scope.creds.secret_key)
            });
```

And then move the Bucket to your `var params`

```
                var params = {
                    Bucket: $scope.creds.bucket,
                    Key: uniqueFileName,
                    ContentType: $scope.file.type,
                    Body: $scope.file,
                    ServerSideEncryption: 'AES256'
                };
```

Comment: Still I get the same error. Should I assign this AWS.Config to some variable as pass it as param to bucket param.. in some way? Because  upto my knowledge , I dont see AWS.Config getting connected to the bucket.putObject

Comment: @sabari I just updated the answer, sorry about that, please try my new suggestion, I think that this should work now. Thanks!

Comment: Tried this Josep. I get the same error 'Missing credentials in config'

Comment: Can I defined something like this : AWS.config.credentials = ...;
as said in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-examples.html

Comment: @sabari sorry, I'm sleepy, I just made another update, please try that, I'm pretty sure that this will get rid of that error.